# Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidity' constructor () public {

Tags: solidity

I'm unsure what identifier it is asking for, can anyone advise?

Error section

```
    constructor () public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: how excatly did u solve the problem.still getting
Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidity' constructor () public {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
```

In the Solidity versions preceding `0.4.22`, the constructor is defined as the function having the same name than the contract.

Example :

```
contract Test {
    function Test() {...}
}
```

So, if you want to use the keyword `constructor` for your constructor, you have to, at least, use the `0.4.22` version of Solidity.

Comment: i've changed  to pragma solidity ^0.4.24; and am still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching an image which contains your code and is working absolutely fine without any Warnings. I have checked it on remix browser .
Please check it out.

[image]

Comment: my code worked perfectly with remix, but not with mist.

Comment: can i see the screenshot?

Comment: I don't have it any more, I solved the issue.