# Can't use constructor() when deploying a contract from ethereum wallet

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, compilation

Take the following code:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract TestCoin {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
}
```

This code works fine locally and works fine in Remix. But when trying to deploy this contract from the Ethereum wallet I get the following error:

```
     Could not compile source code. 
Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidity'
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public {
               ^
```

This question was already asked here, [Expected identifier, got 'eth_compileSolidity' constructor () public {](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51898/expected-identifier-got-eth-compilesolidity-constructor-public). The question was never actually answered but the person who asked the question apparently fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected identifier, got 'eth\_compileSolidity' constructor () public {](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51898/expected-identifier-got-eth-compilesolidity-constructor-public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer.

The Ethereum wallet comes bundled with a Solidity compiler. I'm using version 0.10.0 of the Ethereum wallet. The bundled compiler seems to come with support for version 0.4.21 of Solidity.

However the use of the `constructor()` keyword was not introduced until version 0.4.22.

So if you're experiencing the same issue as me, change your code to resemble:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

contract TestCoin {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    function TestCoin(uint256 initialSupply) public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
  }
}
```

Comment: A nice answer. Don't forget to mark it as answered, using the green tick, in order to remove the question from the unanswered list. You may have to wait a day or so to be able to do that though.